# Dynamically add FormControl to an InputField template

Tags: angular

I am using an inputFieldComponent from a framework that has no FormControl in the template :

```
export class InputFieldComponent  {
  @ViewChild('input', { static: false }) input;
...
...

}
```

Template:

```
  <input #input type ="text" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
```

Public property viewchild "input" is available and I have also an instance of InputFieldComponent available, lets say "inputFieldObject" . Can I dynamically add FormControl to the input field in this instance/Object?

Since I can't change or extend the component template, goal is to get something like this:

```
<input #input type ="text" [(ngModel)]="value" [formControl]="name"/>
```

Comment: Why would you want to add formControl directive to input field ?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have actually more inputFieldComponents which I want to put under a FormGroup for validation, tracking changes etc

Comment: If you wrap input filed under form field then you will be able to access parent FormGroup using ViewChild

Comment: @Chellappanவ the template can't be changed or extended. its part of a framework

Comment: Since FormControl and FormGroup classes are fundamental building blocks for both reactive and template-driven forms, you will be able to access form controls and form groups using ViewChild.